# javascript jquery: call function with parameters after timeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

How can I call a function like this with parameters applied to it?

```
searchTimer = setTimeout(doSearch, 250);

function doSearch(parameter) {

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use an anonymous function as a wrapper:

```
searchTimer = setTimeout(function () {
    doSearch('parameter');
}, 250);
```